# How to collect data from future dplyr query after one fails?

Tags: sql-server, r, dplyr, dbplyr

Often when I try to collect a lot of data from a SQL Server database, I get a cryptic error message from the `nanodbc` driver. For example,

```
library(dplyr)
res <- collect(tbl(con, "result"))
```

> Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n, ...) : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2525: 08S01: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [err
>
> Result already cleared

From then on, I get the error

> Error:  'SELECT * FROM "result" AS "zzz13" WHERE (0 = 1)' nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 08S01: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQ

whenever I try to collect data from a table in the database. This continues until I restart my R session.

Has anyone seen this behavior before or could provide a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One case in which this error definitely occurs :
when there is a `varchar` type column in the table. 
you can check this simply by clicking on the connections pane in rstudio, going to the relevant table and checking the column types.

if the troublesome column is `varchar_col1`, then,

```
sometbl <- tbl(con, in_schema("schema_name","table_with_trouble"))
sometbl %>% head()
```

should reproduce your error.

I am not sure why this happens, but here is a workaround :

```
sometbl <- tbl(con, in_schema("schema_name","table_with_trouble")) %>%
    mutate(alt_col1 = as.character(varchar_col1)) %>%
    select(-varchar_col1)
sometbl %>% head()
```

should work.

Comment: It seems that varchar(max) columns have to be put at the end of SELECT statements when using SQL Server https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/10